# ListBox: Item selected is not highlighted

Tags: wpf, listbox

In my WPF application, I have a simple listbox:

```
                 <ListBox x:Name="lbUtilities">
                    <ListBoxItem Tag="2" Content="One" IsSelected="True" />
                    <ListBoxItem Tag="5" Content="Two" />
                 </ListBox>
```

The problem is that when the ListBox appears first time, the selected item ("One") is not highlighted. If I click on any item, it gets highlighted. How could I have the selected by default item to be highlighted to the system color?

Thanks.

Comment: SelectedIndex="0" for the ListBox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is selected but you need a hightlight for not focused

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lbUtilities">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightCyan"/>
                <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightGray" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBoxItem Tag="2" Content="One" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ListBoxItem Tag="5" Content="Two" />
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Didn't work  ... the item is actually selected even with my code, but the background doesn't differ from other items.

Comment: That works. Could you please explain why I need that trigger? It works without it.

Comment: You don't need the triggers.  That was just in my existing code and I wanted to show the difference.

Comment: This works for initial display or if I select an item and then move off the list.  But after taking an action (e.g., button that updates the list) which uses the PropertyChangedEventHandler(), the highlight disappears.

Comment: @IronRod - ignore the previous comment; bug in my code.  Really dislike the fact that I can't delete a comment when I've been stupid. :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
<Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=lbUtilities}">
    <ListBox Name="lbUtilities" SelectedIndex="0" >
        <ListBoxItem Content="One"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Two"></ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with the listview control where the selected item was highlighted only from user clicking on it, not from code behind such as:

```
MyListView.SelectedItem = SomeObjectInItemsSource
```

I saw that the item was effectively selected but not highlighted as defined in my ItemContainerStyle. Then i tried something else:

```
With CType(MyListView.ItemsSource,IList) 
    .MyListView.SelectedIndex = .IndexOf(SomeObjectInItemsSource)
End With
```

then it started to work just as expected.