# ListBox Mvvm - Hilight selected item

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox

I've a simple listbox bound to ICollectionView.
When I execute something like MyCollection.MoveCurrentToPosition(index) I can see selected item event fired by my listbox, however I can't see any item hilighted.

How can I hilight a listbox item when CurrentItem of my collection view changes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListBox: Item selected is not highlighted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725488/listbox-item-selected-is-not-highlighted)

Comment: MyListBox is bound to List<int> and int type haven't a IsSelected property. So, I cannot highlight anything?

Comment: Ok, I've solved with FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=lbUtilities}"

Comment: Did you try that Link.  IsSelected is not required.